# Currently Liferay Portal CE is installed on java 32 bit, is it harmless, if I reinstall java to 64 bit?

Tags: 64-bit, java

Currently Liferay Portal CE is installed on java x32, is it harmless, if I reinstall java to x64?
And which configuration files I need to change if I reinstall java to x64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "Reinstalling it" ?

By simply changing JAVA_HOME environment variable and adding the 64-bits binaries at the beginning of your path, everything should work.

Comment: I install java x64 binaries, and change PATH and JAVA_HOME variable but, when I start a glassfish it uses java x32.

Comment: Ok, this should fix it : Glassfish stores the **absolue** path to Java binaries in $GLASSFISH_HOME/config/asenv.conf so you may want to check this file

Answer (score 0):

Liferay is just a set of APIs and bunch of web apps called portlets, themes, layouts etc. It comes with the standard containers and servers like Tomcat, JBoss etc.

If Tomcat/JBoss works well with the Java 64 bit, Liferay will too work with that.

I don't think Liferay will have any issue with the architecture. It depends on the compatibility of JVM that you have.

Comment: I have reinstalled java to 64 bit, but when i see to log, it uses 32bit "INFO: JVM invocation command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe", how to change the path to 64-bit, and I've written PATH and JAVA_HOME to new installed java, also, when I try to increase memory for Glassfish it rises error

Comment: Error with content, that could not reserve enough space for object heap, could not create JVM

Comment: added tag x64 for better context of the question